# HTML.TextAreaFor MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textarea

I have a large amount of text data that I want to display in something like a HTML.TextAreaFor().  I tried this using the readonly html property.  However, the user can still select the date and click into the box.  It's confusing for the user.  Is there another control I can use or are ther other attrubutes of the HTML.TextAreaFor() that I can use to make it look un-edittable.

```
@Html.TextArea("SOWDescription", Model.SowDescription,
     new { rows = 5, cols = 50, @class = "celltext2", @readonly="true" })
```

TextAreaFor
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "unselectable" attribute. And it does invalidate the HTML. In CSS 3.0, this is the only way to dis-allow selecting text.

See: [CSS 3.0 user-select property replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152526/css-3-0-user-select-property-replacement)

Answer (score 5):

You could just put it in something like a div and allow it to scroll using css:

```
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: scroll;">@Model.SowDescription</div>
```

Comment: @twaggs...cool, what are the CSS properties I would use.  I'm new to MVC3

Comment: @MikeTWebb I updated his answer to show the css, the most important part obviously is `overflow: scroll`

Comment: You'll want to set the width and height on the containing element (div in the example) and see overflow: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: If you only want it to scroll in one direction you can independently restrict overflow for x/y (ie. `overflow-y: scroll` for only vertical scrolling)

Comment: @Twaggs....that's great info...but, kind of the same issue as the TextAreaFor.  The user can click into the div and highlight text even though they can't edit it...hmmmmm.  Ideas?

Comment: See this SO question for how to disable selection highlighting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting you can add those inline in that `style` attribute on the DIV, or use a class and apply it to any divs like this.

Comment: What Paul said. I'm new to SO, should I edit the answer with the additional styles for disabling selection?

Comment: @Paul...Visual Studio is saying that user-select: is no longer available in CSS 3.0.  Any ideas on what the alternative would be?